# Good hash function for ip addresses and remote ports

Tags: java, ip-address, port, hashset, hash-function

I'm writing a peer to peer application and I need a hash function for storing IP/port pairs in a java hashset.  Rather than re-invent the wheel I wondered if there are already solutions out there but google has not yielded much.

Can anyone recommend a hash function for IPv4 (bonus if it works for IPv6 as well!) and a remote port number?

The port number is likely to be the same unless the client is on the same host in which case it will be sequential.

Comment: what's wrong with converting it to binary 48 bit values (32 ip + 16 port)?

Comment: Hmm maybe but the hash function needs to return a 32bit int

Comment: you can XOR the port with the lower 16 bits of the ip. If you just want a good simple hash function, check out FNV. http://isthe.com/chongo/tech/comp/fnv/

Comment: Thanks.  I just found this http://eternallyconfuzzled.com/tuts/algorithms/jsw_tut_hashing.aspx also

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `String.hashCode()` is pretty reasonable. I would simply do this:

```
int hash = (ip + "/" + port).hashCode();
```

It is "random" enough for coding purposes, so much so that it is relied upon by much of the JDK API.

Remember this mantra... "less code is good"

Comment: Very efficient: It's called very often in virtually every java program, and it's highly optimized. Anyway, you shouldn't worry about efficiency at this low level unless you *notice* a problem... trust the JDK.

Answer (score 1):

`ip^port` is about as simple as you can get

this is pretty decent as the last few bits in the IP number are essentially random (assignment of ip from the ISP)

you can expand that with `ip^port|port>>>16` to avoid the issue with ending on all 0 or 1 being avoided

for IPv6 you'll need to `ipv6_1^ipv6_2^ipv6_3^ipv6_4^port` (with `ipv6_i` being the `i`th 32bit part)

you can also do

```
int hash=17;
hash=hash*5+ip;
hash=hash*5+port;
return hash
```

or

```
int hash=17;
hash=hash*5+ipv6_1;
hash=hash*5+ipv6_2;
hash=hash*5+ipv6_3;
hash=hash*5+ipv6_4;
hash=hash*5+port;
return hash
```

as your standard hash function which is a bit better than the standard xor because it is not commutative and you can change the order around if you feel better about it